# How to get correct threshold level for CFAR (Constant False alarm algorithm)?

Tags: algorithm, matlab, threshold

1. I have taken fourier transform for a sinusoidal signal (with noise added). I have to pass the values to the **CFAR algorithm** (a function) and get back the threshold values in my main matlab file.
2. After getting the values I plot the same and I get a graph as shown in the screenshots. Obviously the ***threshold values are above the signal and not on the signal*** (like a threshold line to differentiate between noise and the useful target).

Can anyone help me how to get the threshold at the right place or what I might be possibly doing wrong? Thanks for any pointers or hints to approach the problem.

[image: SIGNAL WITH THRESHOLD]

PS: I am not permitted to post the code due to obvious reasons.

Comment: Your reasons are not obvious.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.

Comment: The question might not be obvious to you, but as far as my understanding the problem here is @Sack11 did not normalize his filter coefficients. So that the CFAR filtering result is staying above the original signal. So my question here is, why did you downvote my answer below? I am expecting a logical explanation, not just an easy downvote!

Comment: @Andreas and @ Schorsch: I'm not *permitted* means it is very well obvious that due to internal security reasons I'm not supposed to post or publish the code anywhere online.. (I have no permission)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably not normalizing your filter coefficients. Here is a sample code:

```
% Reference and guard cells
winRef=10; 
winGuard=5; 

% Filter coefficients
win=[ones(1,winRef),zeros(1,winGuard),ones(1,winRef)];
win=win/sum(win); % normalize

% CFAR
cfar=conv(signal,win,'same');
```

Comment: This was a very helpful answer to make my progress. Thanks again Ozcan. I appreciate the help. I had not normalized the filter coefficients exactly as you said. :)

Comment: I was able to get the correct plot after following your suggestions.